# QGis2.8 ValueMap: Why is the first row of my ComboBox empty?

Tags: qgis, combo-box

I define a field of a vector layer as ValueMap. I define the values manually, then the feature attribute dialog appears with the combobox. But the first row in my combobox is empty.
I use QGis2.8. In QGis2.0 the first row was not empty.

[image]

[image]

Why is the first row of my ComboBox empty?
If I click "ok" immediately without using the combobox I get a strange character () in the attribut tablel.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have to define which attribute of your combo box you want to use when editing. the "strange" () characters equals to an empty box with no attribute defined.